# Got an error when calling method from Activity A to Activity B

Tags: android, sms

I want to increase progress in a progressbar when I receive a SMS (test on two emulators)  but I got an error - unexpectedly, force close.

Here's my code in Activity A:

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progresslevel);
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      while (progressStatus < 50000) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
          }
        });
      }
  }).start();
```

Increase method in Activity A:

```
public static void increaseValue(Boolean isSMS) {
  if (isSMS == true) {
    progressStatus += 5000;
  } else {
    progressStatus += 7000;
  }
}
```

My Activity SMSReceiver:

```
public class SMSReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      FloCareActivity.increaseValue(true);
    }
}
```

How to fix it ?

Error from log cat :

```
    06-28 11:24:33.733: W/dalvikvm(915): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
06-28 11:24:33.733: E/AndroidRuntime(915): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver nth.flocare.demo.SMSReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nth.flocare.demo.SMSReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43757c18
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2520)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:116)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1843)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nth.flocare.demo.SMSReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43757c18
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2513)
06-28 11:24:33.763: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  ... 10 more
06-28 11:24:33.813: I/dalvikvm(915): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
06-28 11:24:33.895: I/dalvikvm(915): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-28 11:29:33.833: I/Process(915): Sending signal. PID: 915 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you add your error log from logcat?

Comment: Can you check DDMS for the actual exception and stacktrace?

Comment: @SudarNimalan : logcat's above

Comment: the log says its looking for nth.flocare.demo.SMSReceiver but your class is called SMSReceive, make sure your entry in AndroidManifest for the receiver is correct.

Comment: You should still get rid of that thread.  It's going to eat battery power for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

It means Your manifest telling android you have a class named `nth.flocare.demo.SMSReceiver`, and Android cannot find it.

**The Error you have done is**

You have class name as `SMSReceive` in Code and Android is trying to find `nth.flocare.demo.SMSReceiver` So rename your class to `SMSReceiver`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a tight loop in a `Thread` you have created posting new `Runnable`s to a `Handler` event loop as fast as it can go. You haven't posted enough code or a stack trace that would enable us to see if this is the only problem, but it's certainly one that needs to be fixed.  Post messages only when the progress value changes. And certainly there is no need for a separate thread to do it. It's a very fast operation.  Additional threads should be used only to prevent the UI thread from being delayed by a long operation.